# Удалить строки в DataFrame удовлетворяющие условию

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, анализ-данных

Как удалить строки в Pandas DataFrame, в которых значения в столбце `STP == 1005092`?

**Подробно:**

Я занимаюсь обработкой данных в `Jupyter notebook`: нормальное распределение, спектрограммы, гистограммы и тп. У меня есть 1500 тысячи проиндексированных массивов внутри одного файла (Индекс ''STP''). Есть 2 массива которые не подходят по показаниям (явно выделяются из остальных 1498 значений), но проходят тест на нормальное распределение, из-за чего не фильтруются программой. Я пробовал команды `data.STP.remove(1005072)`, где семизначное число - это индекс массива, но все тщетно.

Код:

```
cols = ['ttt','IK05','IK06','IK07','IK08','IK10','IK11','IK14','IK16','IK20','DA05','DA06','DA07','DA08','DA10','DA11','DA14','DA16', 'DA20',
'GZ1','GZ2','GZ3','GZ4', 'LLS', 'LLD', 'STP']

def lasread (fname):
    data = pd.read_table(fname, delim_whitespace = True,na_values = '-999.25', index_col=False)
    return data[cols]

data = None

for name in las: 
    print(name)
    if data is None:
        data = lasread (name)
    else:
        data = pd.concat([data, lasread (name)])

ndata = data.STP.as_matrix(columns=None)

df = data[cols]

df1 = df.groupby('STP')
df1.head()
dfp  = pd.DataFrame()


for name, group in df1:
     k,p=stats.mstats.normaltest(group[5:-5])
     dfp[name] = p

d=dfp.transpose()
d.columns = cols
goodindex = d[d.IK20>0.05][d.DA20>0.05].index - отбраковка по СКО
**data.STP.remove(1005072)**

filtereddata = data[cols][data.STP == -39]

for f in goodindex:
     a = data[cols][data.STP == f]
     filtereddata = pd.concat([filtereddata, a])
print(filtereddata)
```

Comment: Вы можете привести небольшой пример данных (конфиденциальные данные стоит предварительно скрыть)?

Comment: Да, пожалуйста: 

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TpdZS6FqVtgt7F4kZreXSegWgMr7-N8o

Comment: где вы определяете `d` (`d[d.IK20>0.05][d.DA20>0.05].index`)?

Comment: Перед Goodindex. Не вставилась почему-то.... 

        `d=dfp.transpose()`
        `d.columns = cols`

Comment: Вы можете уточнить вопрос? Вы хотите отфильтровать DataFrame по определенному критерию? Укажите этот критерий(ии) пожалуйста...

Comment: Да, я фильтрую по критериям 
     `d[d.IK20>0.05][d.DA20>0.05]`

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь я смогу получить совет?

Comment: Ну тогда я жду с нетерпением :)

Comment: Что-то я недопонимаю... В ваших данных есть только три уникальных значения STP: `array([1005092., 1006062., 1007054.])` - вы же хотите удалить `1005072` - можете пояснить что вы хотите отфильтровать?

Comment: Я Вам скинул демоверсию всего пакета данных. Я хочу удалить, допустим, все строки, в которых "STP" присвоено значение `1005092`.
`1005072` - в оригинальном файле, весом 150 мб :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Чтобы отфильтровать (удалить строки) DataFrame по критерию: "удалить строки в которых значения в столбце `STP == 1005092`"

**Вариант 1**: фильтруем по одному значению:

```
df = df.loc[df['STP'] != 1005092]
```

**Вариант 2**: можно указать несколько значений:

```
df = df.loc[~df['STP'].isin([1005092])]
```

**Вариант 3**: фильтруем по одному значению:

```
df = df.query("STP != 1005092")
```

**Вариант 4**: можно указать несколько значений:

```
df = df.query("STP not in [1005092, ...]")
```

**Вариант 5**:

```
df = df.drop(np.where(df['STP'] == 1005092)[0])
```

**Примеры:**

```
In [69]: new = df.loc[~df['STP'].isin([1005092])]

In [70]: df.shape
Out[70]: (1488, 26)

In [71]: new.shape
Out[71]: (978, 26)

In [72]: new2 = df.query("STP != 1005092")

In [73]: new3 = df.query("STP not in [1005092]")

In [74]: new.equals(new2)
Out[74]: True

In [75]: new.equals(new3)
Out[75]: True
```

PS объединить данные из нескольких CSV (с одинаковой структурой) можно следующим образом:

```
def read_all_csv(files, **kwargs):
    return pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, **kwargs) for f in files], ignore_index=True)

cols = ['ttt','IK05','IK06','IK07','IK08','IK10','IK11','IK14','IK16','IK20',
        'DA05','DA06','DA07','DA08','DA10','DA11','DA14','DA16', 'DA20','GZ1',
        'GZ2','GZ3','GZ4', 'LLS', 'LLD', 'STP']

# read them all                       
df = read_all_csv(las, usecols=cols, delim_whitespace=True, na_values='-999.25')
```

Comment: Ого! Спасибо! Сейчас проверю :)

Comment: Благодарю за дополнение, буду время от времени прибегать к нему :) 

Кстати, я попробовал вариант с функцией `.isin` , и `new.shape` правда показал изменения в количестве строк, но нужная стоянка не ушла. В чем я неправ? 

`new = df.loc[~df['STP'].isin([1005072])]
df.shape
(871122, 26)

new.shape
(870202, 26)`

Comment: @ГеоргийМоскалев, наверное указали не ту "стоянку"... Я надеюсь вы проверяли в `new`, а не в `df`?

Comment: Да нет, именно ту стоянку я и указал :)

Да, именно в `new` я и проверял

Comment: Т.е. `new[new['STP'] == 1005072]` - возвращает непустой DataFrame? "Не верю!" (с) Станиславский...

Comment: :))) сейчас проверю

Comment: Все работает! Большое спасибо!

Comment: Баллов пока не хватает, но уверен, что это не последняя наша встреча :) 

Спасибо еще раз за ответы, они очень помогли :)

Comment: @ГеоргийМоскалев, пожалуйста :)